# Sending data to non-existing SignalR connection succeeds?

Tags: asp.net, signalr

I am sending data to specific connections by using the extension method to send to a single connection id:

```
var context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetConnectionContext<PriceConnection>();
context.Connection.Send(connectionId, values);
```

If I send to a connection id that does not exist - nothing happens.

Is that by design?

I was expecting some sort of execption being thrown or some notification that I am doing something that does not really make sense.

I am using PersistentConnections on SignalR 1.1.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's by design. We never send to the connection directly inline.

Comment: Is there a way to check if a specific connection id is "alive" server side?

Comment: Nope, there's no way to know that as the client may be on a different machine.

Comment: Not entirely true. It's possible to check if a connection ID is alive by performing a handshake (send a message asking the client to respond). This, of course, is time consuming. You have to provide quite a bit of time to allow for a slow client. Another alternative is to program the client to send a heartbeat. That is, send a message at continuous intervals. If you haven't got a message within some unit of time, the client can be considered disconnected. Neither, of course, are specific SignalR functionalities and just general purpose networking techniques.